# How can I pass a variable in aws cli command in bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am unable to pass a variable in the tag-user cli command.

```
A=$(aws iam list-user-tags --user-name user --query 'Tags[].{Key:Key,Value:Value}' | grep -B2 "Description" | grep Value | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | tr -d '",'| awk '$1=$1')
```

```
aws iam list-user-tags --user-name user --query 'Tags[].{Key:Key,Value:Value}' | grep -B2 "Description" | grep Value
        "Value": "Used for SSO",
```

**A=Used for SSO**

**passing the value of A to the below CLI :**

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name azure-sso-user --tags "[{"Key": "own:team","Value": "test@test.com"},{"Key": "security","Value": "Service"},{"Key": "comment","Value": "$A"}]"
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tags': Invalid JSON:
[{Key: own:team,Value: test@test.com},{Key: security,Value: Service},{Key: own:comment,Value: Used
```

Comment: Is the value of A valid Json?

Comment: Also, pass --tags in double quotes but use single quotes for the actual keys and values.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I find your way better than approved answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name user --tags '[{"Key": "own:team","Value": "test@test.com"},{"Key": "security","Value": "Service"},{"Key": "own:comment","Value": "'"$A"'"}]'
```

That is, using the following:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "own:team",
        "Value": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "security",
        "Value": "Service"
    },
    {
        "Key": "own:comment",
        "Value": "'"
        $A
        "'"
    }
]
```